# AJAX, preforming mathematical function on array returned, results as NaN?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am making an ajax call to update a bootstrap progress bar, and on sucess of the AJAX call i have this:

```
$(function () {
    var percent = data['minutes'] / 30 * 100;

    $('#progressbarr').html("<div class='bar' id='progressbar' style='width: "+ percent +"%;'></div>");
}
```

Now, i know data['minutes'] returns a number, couse i use it elsewhere, from the same ajax call, but when i do matehematical operations that include that data array, i get Not a number????

I am 100% sure data['minutes'] returns a numerical value

**EDIT 1**

All the JS

```
setInterval(function(){

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST", // Can be "GET"
         url: "ajax.php",
         data: {
             },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
        {
            $(function () {

                var timeMinutes = data['minutes']; //get comment to post

                var percent = parseInt(data['minutes']) / 30 * 100;


                $('#progressbarr').html("<div class='bar' id='progressbar' style='width: "+ percent +"%;'></div>");
                $('#tid').html(timeMinutes);
            });
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

All the PHP

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `login_attempts` WHERE ip = '$ip'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $banned = $row['date'];
}

$start_date = new DateTime($today);
$since_start = new DateTime($banned);

$interval = $start_date->diff($since_start);
$minutes = $interval->days * 24 * 60;
$minutes += $interval->h * 60;
$minutes += $interval->i;

$TTL['minutes'] = 30-$minutes;

echo json_encode($TTL);
```

Comment: just to be safe, try it with `parseInt(data['minutes'])` and see if it works. i know you said twice for sure it is a number, but humor me.

Comment: `data['minutes']` is probably `undefined`, which suggests that this code is running before the Ajax completes. Perhaps you are correct that `data['minutes']` *eventually* holds a numeric value, but it doesn't at the time this code runs.

Comment: when console is inspected, POST does return the numerical value

Comment: @JohnDOe Just out of curiosity why do you have `$(function () { })` inside the success callback? You do realize that is the same as `$(document).ready(function () { });` and is executed when the page is ready not when the **ajax** call returns. You're success callback actually runs on `$(document).ready()` not on the success of the **ajax** event. Remove the `$(function () {` and closing `});` from the success callback and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `$()` surrounding your ajax callback, remove it and everything should work.

Failing jsfiddle (based on your code): http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/fnjMM/1/

Working jsfiddle (without the `$()`): http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/fnjMM/2/

Comment: Your fiddle works just as well without the `+`, which suggests the OP's problem (whatever it is) is not addressed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to a numerical type first using something like:

```
var percent = parseInt(data['minutes']) / 30 * 100;
```

Comment: `alert(typeof data['minutes']); alert(data['minutes']);` And eventually `parseInt(data['minutes']) || 0`.

Comment: Sorry, `data['minutes']` isn't what you think it is then.  put this immediately before your calculation: `alert(parseInt(data['minutes']))`

Comment: well .. this is odd ... getting NaN on the alert ... maybe you could help me get to the root then i get a date from a MySQL date feild, and then i do $start_date->diff($since_start); to get the interval between now and the saved date, $TTL['minutes'] = 30-$minutes; i then subtract the time, and then echo it with echo json_encode($TTL);

Comment: Please edit your question so we can see where and how `data` is set - you mention you're using AJAX, you're probably trying to access `data` before it has been set.